# CURL not working from web browser on Red Hat, Apache, PHP, AWS

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, curl, redhat

I have a PHP script on a Red Hat AWS server running Apache:

```
$url = "https://testsite.com/testfile.txt";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo "http_code=".$responseInfo['http_code']."\n".$response."\n";
curl_close($ch);
```

When I run it from the SSH terminal, it works. But if I load the page in a web browser, it returns "http_code=0". In both cases, curl_error returns nothing.

What I need to do to allow CURL to work from a web browser?

Comment: It works in Amazon Linux 2 AMI, so I think my solution is just going to be to use that until I can find a solution for RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

As no error is generated, it can be assumed that curl is working, but you are not getting the desired result.

There may be more than one reason behind it -

> First of all check outbound rules in the security group, it may be failing there
>
> Secondly may be due to https, try using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
>
> Also check if libcurl is installed or not

If trying the above 3 things did not work then have to look for other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 1) Outbound rules are "all traffic". The same security group works on an Amazon Linux AMI. 2) CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER didn't work. 3) libcurl is installed. It works from the terminal. ‍♂️

Comment: http code = 0 means there is some error in the url, but you have mentioned the same url worked from SSH, please cross check if the url is ok in your PHP code

Comment: Yes, it's the same file in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

As you're running on a RHEL Distro, I'd guess it's an SELinux issue. A guide on configuring SELinux for Apache/httpd on RHEL can be found [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/changing-selinux-states-and-modes_using-selinux).

Setting SELinux Policy to *Permissive* would resolve your issue. **BUT READ FROM THE ABOVE LINK ABOUT IMPLICATIONS BEFORE DOING SO.**

A more fine tuned fix would be setting the SELinux Flag for httpd_can_network_connect to 'on'. As this has to do with security, do your own reading first, use at your own risk. (Run with sudo if command fails).

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

[Opinions on security implications of turning on the Flag.](https://serverfault.com/questions/1020429/how-much-does-httpd-can-network-connect-being-set-to-1-actually-open-up-on-selin)

[SELinux Booleans list with descriptions.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server-booleans)

[Read a bit more about the 'setsebool' command here.](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setsebool)

[A thread with the same problem.](https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/311042-curl-not-working/)

Comment: Worked for me! I could lynx and address but couldn't curl it with php.