# http_code 0 with Redhat php curl

Tags: php, redhat

I can use lynx to access a website from the server fine. When I try to access the same website with a php curl instruction I get `http_code=>0` from `curl_getinfo($ch);`
The same php code on another redhat server in the same data centre works fine. I have admin access to the server.

I have tried php 7.4 and php 8.0.
`curl` is enabled when I call `phpinfo();`
I am unsure how to debug this error!

It is RHEL 8.8

This is the output from `curl_getinfo($ch);`

> Array ( [url] =>
> https://.....
> [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size]
> => 0    [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0    [total_time] => 0.055895 [namelookup_time] => 0.105978
> [connect_time] => 0    [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0
> [size_download] => 0    [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0
> [download_content_length] => -1    [upload_content_length] => -1
> [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] =>    0 [redirect_url] =>
> [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port]    => 0
> [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [http_version] => 0 [protocol] => 0
> [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => [appconnect_time_us] => 0
> [connect_time_us] => 0 [namelookup_time_us] => 105978
> [pretransfer_time_us] => 0 [redirect_time_us] => 0
> [starttransfer_time_us]    => 0 [total_time_us] => 55895 )

Comment: Setopt CURLOPT_VERBOSE = true, then compare the information between servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

This worked. The full answer is here: [CURL not working from web browser on Red Hat, Apache, PHP, AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201308/curl-not-working-from-web-browser-on-red-hat-apache-php-aws)

Answer (score 0):

> I can use lynx to access a website

Probably you can't access it via curl cli because of the cookies.

```
# err
$ curl https:// --verbose
# suc
$ curl https:// \
      --verbose \
      --cookie="/tmp/cookie.txt" \
      --cookie-jar="/tmp/cookie.txt"
```

PHP representation

```php
$cookieFile = '/tmp/cookie.txt';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
   CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookieFile,
   CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookieFile,
   // other options
]);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: No change. I set the cookie to cookie.txt instead of /tmp/cookie.txt but I get the same error and no response